# Best practice: global.master calls multiple scripts But not all needed

Tags: javascript, performance

I am looking for Best practice, Our global master calls multiple js scripts. On page load all scripts get call but not all needed on certain pages. I am using asp.net.

example:

globalmaster:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="website/js/calender.js"></script>
<script src="website/js/home.js"></script>
<script src="website/js/example.js"></script> 
**example js also pulls/loads:
  <script src="website/js/example1.js"></script> 
  <script src="website/js/example2.js"></script>
```

home.aspx:
I only need:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="website/js/home.js"></script>
```

My main concern is load times. We pull a lot of un-needed js (depending on the page). I understand i could just call individual script tags per page (this would be easier if the site was small).

Comment: asyncing/deffering js or even cs the only way to go?

Comment: "*I understand i could just call individual script tags per page*" - yes, do that, it'll improve load times. What exactly is your question?

Comment: ok bergi,  i was just wondering if there was any other solutions my googling could not find. Im working on a largeee website